# How to know distro features

Tags: yocto, imx6

I am building image for NXP board using yocto. I could see different distros say "x11, wayland, fb, directfb" etc.

In the conf files for these distros I could see "DISTRO_FEATURES_remove" of other distros. Say in x11 distro conf file "DISTRO_FEATURES_remove="wayland"" is there.

I need to check what features provided by each distro. Say I need to check the features provided by wayland and x11 distros.

Can you guide to check in yocto source folder for the features provided by these distros.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are asking, "how do I know what's in DISTRO_FEATURES for a given distro?" If so, DISTRO_FEATURES is a variable that is set in a configuration and loaded/overloaded as needed to drive contents you want to add to your system. Various recipes check the contents of DISTRO_FEATURES to enable/disable different features. You can do the same to test as needed.

For example, some recipes may use the following to check to see if the configuration has enabled a features. Our custom linux kernel recipe uses the following to specify specific configuration files for the recipe.

```
{@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'bluez5', 'file://bluetooth.cfg', '', d)} \
```

Generically, you turn features on or off by specifying contents for DISTRO_FEATURES on your own.

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-DISTRO_FEATURES

If you need to see the contents of DISTRO_FEATURES from the command line

```
bitbake -e imagename | grep "^DISTRO_FEATURES"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If we want to enable a feature for the distro then how we will know the feature name? Say the feature name is "bluetooth" or "bluez5". If we want to select a feature for the distro then that should be supported by yocto. How to know that the feature is alreary supported so that I can select that feature for the distro?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you are adding. However, DISTRO_FEATURES is just a space separated list of strings. It is used by querying the list for a string your recipe or another recipe or class would then use to enable/disable some specific part of that recipe or class. Usage depends on need here.

Comment: Minor thing that tripped me up briefly - that `{@bb.utils...` line probably should have a leading `$` - i.e. `${@bb.utils...` if used in `SRC_URI`.